# tkinter for loop entry bind connected to sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, bind

I am having difficulty in returning the right sqlite3 row with a bind of an entry created in for loop

i know, i don't know how to explain it with words so here's the piece of code

```
    if x == '':
        counter_kit_label = 10
        for kit in find_everything_from_db('*', 'kit'):
            kit_label = tk.Label(self.kit_listbox, text=f"{kit[0]}, {kit[1].capitalize()}, {kit[2].capitalize()},",
                                 bg='white')
            kit_label.place(x=5, y=counter_kit_label)
            kit_label.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: evidenzia(event))
            kit_label.bind('<Leave>', lambda event: non_evidenzia(event))
            kit_label.bind('<Button-1>', lambda: None)  # todo: creare event bind
            kit_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
            kit_entry = tk.Entry(self.kit_listbox, textvariable=kit_entry_var)
            kit_entry_var.set(f"{kit[4].capitalize()}")
            kit_entry.place(x=108, y=counter_kit_label)
            kit_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.modifica_luogo_kit(kit_entry.get(), kit, event))
            counter_kit_label += 30
    else:
        pass
def modifica_luogo_kit(self,luogo, kit, event=None):
    print(event.widget.get())
    print(kit)
```

when i run the script and press 'return-key' on the first tk.Entry, the print result of "print(event.widget.get())" correspond to the first entry preset from the first row of sqlite3 tab but "print(kit)" correspond to the latest row of sqlite3 tab

Comment: Have you tried using `functools.partial` instead of `lambda`?

Comment: no, i don't know how to use functools.partial yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def modifica_luogo_kit(luogo, kit, event=None):
    print("Data in widget =", luogo.get())
    print("Entry number:", kit)

root = tk.Tk()

for kit in range(10):
    kit_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    kit_entry.pack()
    command = partial(modifica_luogo_kit, kit_entry, kit)
    kit_entry.bind("<Return>", command)
```

I removed all of the unnecessary details to make it easier to solve the problem. I used `functools.partial` to create a command that is executed when "`<Return>`" is pressed. For more info on `functools.partial` look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).